# Replacing `Zero Width No-Break Space` with `space` in R

Tags: regex, r, text-mining

I want to replace `Zero Width No-Break Space` with `space` in a `Persian text` using `R`.
I used the code like this according to [this link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm).

```
testAdrs<-"خيابان‌ مولوي‌نرسيده‌به‌قيام‌"
testAdrs<-gsub('\xef\xbb\xbf',' ',testAdrs)
```

I want my `testAdrs` to be like `"خيابان‌ مولوي‌ نرسيده‌ به‌ قيام‌"`, however
there is no change in my string.

what is the problem?

Comment: did you try `gsub("[[:space:]]", " ", testAdrs)`?

Comment: @hrbrmstr thanks. that does not work.

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian Thanks for your comment. I want it to be automatic, and someone answer it below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I examined your text `'خيابان‌ مولوي‌نرسيده‌به‌قيام‌'` on my terminal, I got:

```
>>> خيابان\U+200C مولوي\U+200Cنرسيده\U+200Cبه\U+200Cقيام\U+
```

and converted all these chars to hex in python shell, I got:

```
>>> binascii.unhexlify(binascii.hexlify(u"خيابان\U+200C مولوي\U+200C نرسيده\U+200C به\U+200C قيام\U+200C".encode('utf-16'))).decode('utf-16')
u'\u062e\u064a\u0627\u0628\u0627\u0646\u200c \u0645\u0648\u0644\u0648\u064a\u200c \u0646\u0631\u0633\u064a\u062f\u0647\u200c \u0628\u0647\u200c \u0642\u064a\u0627\u0645\u200c'
```

You will see that there is no `\ufeff`("ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE") in the output of the program above. An another proof is [here](https://regex101.com/r/lB8pZ1/1) you will see that `ǎ` easily be matched but non of `\x{feff}` is existed.

Thus, the problem of yours is no "ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE" in your string. I guess kind of space that you want to replace might be [this one](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm) `\u200C`("ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER").

Comment: Thanks @fronthem I used `testAdrs<-gsub('\u{200c}',' ',testAdrs)` and it worked.